# Stripe filter transfer by creation date

Tags: rest, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve yesterday's transfer for one of our customers. Please check the following curl request

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic ourPrivateKeyEncoded' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data destination=acct_anAccount \
  --data created.gt=1629676800
```

I'm able to retrieve **all** the transfers of my customer, but the `created` filter is not accepted. Meaning the above request without the `created.gt` is ok.

With this filter Stripe respond me a 400 with this body

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: created.gt. Did you mean created?",
    "param": "created.gt",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

I'm following [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/list?lang=curl#list_transfers-created-lt), the created filter seems to exist. Does someone have an idea why Stripe doesn't accept my filter?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `created.gt` by `created[gt]` filter key made my request works.

The documentation seems to be outdated

Comment: Glad you got it working!  The documentation you linked to appears to be correct.  The `created.gt` syntax on the left is generic property/object syntax not unique to curl and needs to be adapted based on the tool/language you're using.  For example, in PHP it would look like this: `'created' => ['gt' => $timestamp]`.